# Why is the iteration running so slowly?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I'm normalizing some data in Pandas and the interrows takes a long time. The math seems relatively easy though and there are only ~2500 rows. Is there a faster way to do this?

As you can see below I've manually done the normalizing.

```
# normalize the rating columns to values between 0 and 1
df_1['numerator_norm'] = ((df_1['rating_numerator']- df_1['rating_numerator'].min())/(df_1['rating_numerator'].max()- df_1['rating_numerator'].min()))
df_1['denominator_norm'] = ((df_1['rating_denominator']- df_1['rating_denominator'].min())/(df_1['rating_denominator'].max()- df_1['rating_denominator'].min()))
df_1['normalized_rating'] = np.nan

for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
    df_1['normalized_rating'][index] = (df_1['numerator_norm'][index] / df_1['denominator_norm'][index])
```

It would be nice to have this process in only a few seconds instead of ~60 seconds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
    df_1['normalized_rating'][index] = (df_1['numerator_norm'][index] / 
df_1['denominator_norm'][index])
```

to:

```
df_1['normalized_rating'] = df_1['numerator_norm'] / df_1['denominator_norm']
```

for vectorized division.

`Iterrows` is best avoid, check [Does iterrows have performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002)